# Change one of the bootstrap's background transparency without affecting text

Tags: html, css

I made a div with a background, in this case bg-secondary, I want to set the background's transparency to 0.6, however, I don't want to make the text inside of the div more transparent, only the background

I tried to override the bootstrap setup making a css style called bg-secondary with an opacity of 0.6 but it also makes the text more transparent and I don't want that, I just want the background more transparent

My div:

```
<div class="text-light bg-secondary">
    <h3>hi</h3>
      <h5>lorem ipsum<br></h5>
</div>
```

Style

```
<style>
    .bg-secondary {
        opacity: 0.6;    
    }
</style>
```

Sorry for such basic question but I am getting really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use css `rgba(red, green, blue, opacity)` to set opacity exclusively on the parent element's background property.

But note that Bootstrap v4 sets css:

```
.bg-secondary {
   background-color: #6c757d!important;
}
```

Also, because **hexadecimal** rgba() is still [lacking comprehensive browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa), it's advisable to [convert hexadecimal](http://www.hex2rgba.devoth.com/) #6c757d into it's decimal equivalent.  In your case the Bootstrap override would be:

```
.bg-secondary {
  background-color: rgba(108, 117, 125, 0.6) !important;
}
```

For your style to **override** bootstrap's style definition, you must define it **after** the bootstrap stylesheet and use the `!important` post-fix as well.

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anandamasri/2dnxsmf4/18/).

Answer (score 2):

Opacity will affect the children of the selected element...instead use rgba colors to set translucent backgrounds.

Example:

Instead of this:

```
.bg-secondary {
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Try this:

```
.bg-secondary {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Comment: did not work, doesn't change the opacity of the background at all

Comment: I promise it does.  Load your custom css file AFTER bootstrap's css... http://tutorials.jenkov.com/css/precedence.html

Comment: it's not in a custom css file, it's in a style tag in my html file

Comment: Put it in it's own file. https://www.codeconquest.com/how-the-separation-of-concerns-makes-programming-magic/

Comment: @FAKETAXI, it doesn't matter if it's in a custom file or not - it needs to be defined after the bootstrap import AND it needs the ```!important``` post-fix (because the bootstrap declaration is: ```background-color: #6c757d!important;```).